# Vue/Laravel WebSockets Listening more than one event

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, websocket

I have some problems developing WebSockets with Laravel and Vue. Until now everything worked fine until I needed to implement a function that will listen to more events on one channel. The interesting part is that I can see in the console that both events are received but for one I'm getting that pusher has no callbacks on that channel and listener.
So what I did actually.

I created 2 events in my Laravel app like so:

```
    class Order implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    
        public $user;
        public $order;
    
      
        public function __construct($user, $order)
        {
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->order = $order;
        }
    
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            return new PrivateChannel('orders');
        }
    
        public function broadcastAs(){
            return 'order-updated';
        }
    }
```

And another one is

```
class AddOrder implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    public function __construct($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('orders');
    }

    public function broadcastAs(){
        return 'order-added';
    }
}
```

So the first one is for updating orders, and the second for adding. As you see they are connected to the same channel.

And in front-end I did like so:

```
window.Echo.private("orders").listen(".order-updated", (order) => {
            if (this.liveData) {
                let index = this.ordersList.findIndex((singleOrder => singleOrder.id === order.order.id));

                let updateOrder = {
                    updated_index: index,
                    updated_order: order.order
                };
                
                this.$store.commit("UPDATE_ORDER", updateOrder);
            }
        })
        .listen("order-added", (order) => {
            this.$store.commit("ADD_ORDER", order);
        });
```

So, as I see in the console, every WebSocket is sent as needed, but it's only listening to the first class (Order), and when I test another one (AddOrder) I can see the response in the console but after that, I have a log like:

> Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on private-orders for order-added"]

I tried to replace the channel with a presence channel and public channel but I have no success. The interesting part is that I replaced listen to methods, first to listen order-added, and then order-updated, but it's only working for order-updated.

What could be a problem? Why I can't get an order-added listener?

PS: The reason AddOrder has no $user class, is because everyone can make order, and has no need for that class.

Comment: Did you missed "**.**" in `.listen("order-added", (order)` or is it just a typo?

Comment: Yes, I realized that after that post, thanks anyway :)